# CUDA batch out of memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, bert-language-model

I have a small dataset and running a script called LightXML which is on a git:https://github.com/kongds/LightXML

I am getting this error:

```
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 192.00 MiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 4.71 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 4.82 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

I have found multiple posts stating that I should reduce the batch size but I can't seem to find it defined.

The script is halting at:

```
train_loss = model.one_epoch(epoch, trainloader, optimizer, mode='train',
                                 eval_loader=validloader if args.valid else testloader,
                                 eval_step=args.eval_step, log=LOG)
```

The one_epoch method is the following and the script is stalling at `outputs = self(**inputs)`

```
def one_epoch(self, epoch, dataloader, optimizer,
              mode='train', eval_loader=None, eval_step=20000, log=None):

    bar = tqdm.tqdm(total=len(dataloader))
    p1, p3, p5 = 0, 0, 0
    g_p1, g_p3, g_p5 = 0, 0, 0
    total, acc1, acc3, acc5 = 0, 0, 0, 0
    g_acc1, g_acc3, g_acc5 = 0, 0, 0
    train_loss = 0

    if mode == 'train':
        self.train()
    else:
        self.eval()

    if self.use_swa and epoch == self.swa_warmup_epoch and mode == 'train':
        self.swa_init()

    if self.use_swa and mode == 'eval':
        self.swa_swap_params()

    pred_scores, pred_labels = [], []
    bar.set_description(f'{mode}-{epoch}')

    with torch.set_grad_enabled(mode == 'train'):
        for step, data in enumerate(dataloader):
            batch = tuple(t for t in data)
            have_group = len(batch) > 4

            check_memory()
            inputs = {'input_ids':      batch[0].cuda(),
                      'attention_mask': batch[1].cuda(),
                      'token_type_ids': batch[2].cuda()}


            if mode == 'train':
                inputs['labels'] = batch[3].cuda()

                if self.group_y is not None:
                    inputs['group_labels'] = batch[4].cuda()
                    inputs['candidates'] = batch[5].cuda()
            print("------------------------------------------------------------")
            outputs = self(**inputs)
            bar.update(1)


            if mode == 'train':
                loss = outputs[1]
                loss /= self.update_count
                train_loss += loss.item()

                with amp.scale_loss(loss, optimizer) as scaled_loss:
                    scaled_loss.backward()

                if step % self.update_count == 0:
                    optimizer.step()
                    self.zero_grad()

                if step % eval_step == 0 and eval_loader is not None and step != 0:
                    results = self.one_epoch(epoch, eval_loader, optimizer, mode='eval')
                    p1, p3, p5 = results[3:6]
                    g_p1, g_p3, g_p5 = results[:3]
                    if self.group_y is not None:
                        log.log(f'{epoch:>2} {step:>6}: {p1:.4f}, {p3:.4f}, {p5:.4f}'
                                f' {g_p1:.4f}, {g_p3:.4f}, {g_p5:.4f}')
                    else:
                        log.log(f'{epoch:>2} {step:>6}: {p1:.4f}, {p3:.4f}, {p5:.4f}')
                    # NOTE: we don't reset model to train mode and keep model in eval mode
                    # which means all dropout will be remove after `eval_step` in every epoch
                    # this tricks makes LightXML converge fast
                    # self.train()

                if self.use_swa and step % self.swa_update_step == 0:
                    self.swa_step()

                bar.set_postfix(loss=loss.item())
            elif self.group_y is None:
                logits = outputs
                if mode == 'eval':
                    labels = batch[3]
                    _total, _acc1, _acc3, _acc5 =  self.get_accuracy(None, logits, labels.cpu().numpy())
                    total += _total; acc1 += _acc1; acc3 += _acc3; acc5 += _acc5
                    p1 = acc1 / total
                    p3 = acc3 / total / 3
                    p5 = acc5 / total / 5
                    bar.set_postfix(p1=p1, p3=p3, p5=p5)
                elif mode == 'test':
                    pred_scores.append(logits.detach().cpu())
            else:
                group_logits, candidates, logits = outputs

                if mode == 'eval':
                    labels = batch[3]
                    group_labels = batch[4]

                    _total, _acc1, _acc3, _acc5 = self.get_accuracy(candidates, logits, labels.cpu().numpy())
                    total += _total; acc1 += _acc1; acc3 += _acc3; acc5 += _acc5
                    p1 = acc1 / total
                    p3 = acc3 / total / 3
                    p5 = acc5 / total / 5

                    _, _g_acc1, _g_acc3, _g_acc5 = self.get_accuracy(None, group_logits, group_labels.cpu().numpy())
                    g_acc1 += _g_acc1; g_acc3 += _g_acc3; g_acc5 += _g_acc5
                    g_p1 = g_acc1 / total
                    g_p3 = g_acc3 / total / 3
                    g_p5 = g_acc5 / total / 5
                    bar.set_postfix(p1=p1, p3=p3, p5=p5, g_p1=g_p1, g_p3=g_p3, g_p5=g_p5)
                elif mode == 'test':
                    _scores, _indices = torch.topk(logits.detach().cpu(), k=100)
                    _labels = torch.stack([candidates[i][_indices[i]] for i in range(_indices.shape[0])], dim=0)
                    pred_scores.append(_scores.cpu())
                    pred_labels.append(_labels.cpu())


    if self.use_swa and mode == 'eval':
        self.swa_swap_params()
    bar.close()

    if mode == 'eval':
        return g_p1, g_p3, g_p5, p1, p3, p5
    elif mode == 'test':
        return torch.cat(pred_scores, dim=0).numpy(), torch.cat(pred_labels, dim=0).numpy() if len(pred_labels) != 0 else None
    elif mode == 'train':
        return train_loss
```

I am also including the forward function which is stopping at outs=self.bert()

```
def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids,
            labels=None, group_labels=None, candidates=None):
    is_training = labels is not None
   
    outs = self.bert(
        input_ids,
        attention_mask=attention_mask,
        token_type_ids=token_type_ids
    )[-1]

    out = torch.cat([outs[-i][:, 0] for i in range(1, self.feature_layers+1)], dim=-1)

    out = self.drop_out(out)
    group_logits = self.l0(out)

    if self.group_y is None:
        logits = group_logits
        if is_training:
            loss_fn = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
            loss = loss_fn(logits, labels)
            return logits, loss
        else:
            return logits

    if is_training:
        l = labels.to(dtype=torch.bool)
        target_candidates = torch.masked_select(candidates, l).detach().cpu()
        target_candidates_num = l.sum(dim=1).detach().cpu()
    groups, candidates, group_candidates_scores = self.get_candidates(group_logits,
                                                                      group_gd=group_labels if is_training else None)
    if is_training:
        bs = 0
        new_labels = []
        for i, n in enumerate(target_candidates_num.numpy()):
            be = bs + n
            c = set(target_candidates[bs: be].numpy())
            c2 = candidates[i]
            new_labels.append(torch.tensor([1.0 if i in c else 0.0 for i in c2 ]))
            if len(c) != new_labels[-1].sum():
                s_c2 = set(c2)
                for cc in list(c):
                    if cc in s_c2:
                        continue
                    for j in range(new_labels[-1].shape[0]):
                        if new_labels[-1][j].item() != 1:
                            c2[j] = cc
                            new_labels[-1][j] = 1.0
                            break
            bs = be
        labels = torch.stack(new_labels).cuda()
    candidates, group_candidates_scores =  torch.LongTensor(candidates).cuda(), torch.Tensor(group_candidates_scores).cuda()

    emb = self.l1(out)
    embed_weights = self.embed(candidates) # N, sampled_size, H
    emb = emb.unsqueeze(-1)
    logits = torch.bmm(embed_weights, emb).squeeze(-1)

    if is_training:
        loss_fn = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
        loss = loss_fn(logits, labels) + loss_fn(group_logits, group_labels)
        return logits, loss
    else:
        candidates_scores = torch.sigmoid(logits)
        candidates_scores = candidates_scores * group_candidates_scores
        return group_logits, candidates, candidates_scores
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, probably the problem is in the batch_size. Usually batch_size is defined in the DataLoader. In the [main.py](https://github.com/kongds/LightXML/blob/main/src/main.py#L38) you can see:

```
trainloader = DataLoader(train_d, batch_size=args.batch, num_workers=5,
                                 shuffle=True)
```

You can define it at the moment of the script running - args.batch.

Comment: I tried reducing it even to 2 but I still have the same problem

Comment: Probably, the model is too large for your GPU. Try to use Colab or any other services with  large GPU support. Also, you can decrease the size of descriptors or image size in case of images.